# Running query in gremlin-console, getting "Unable to create an OLAP traversal Source when spark is not running or cannot be detected"

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, datastax-enterprise-graph, datastax-startup

according to :

https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/graphAnalytics/northwindDemoGraphSnapshot.html

I connected in OLAP mode and got the above failure.

I did 'dse spark' , successfully . But I don't understand why I cannot run OLAP queries.
Im using datastax dse graph cluster on multiple machines

Comment: if you want to contact your account rep at DataStax he should be able to put you in touch with the startup program SAs to troubleshoot this further.

Answer (score 0):

What does dsetool status display for the DC type?
Did you start the DSE instance as a GraphAnalytics instance as described here http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/admin/startDseService.html?
Are there any error messages in the System.log (/var/log/cassandra/system.log)

Comment: I have a cluster with 8 machines. each machine is configured :            Spark Analytics, DSE Graph, and DSE Search node :
SPARK_ENABLED=1
GRAPH_ENABLED=1
SOLR_ENABLED=1

Comment: maybe there is a connection problem between cassandra and spark. how can I check that?

Comment: in the cassnadra log file I can see connection refused

Comment: Do I have to use Use Kerberos authentication for DSE Graph in production. ? according to https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/sec/kerberosGuidelines.html

Comment: I would like to see cassandra.yaml and dse.yaml configuration files for example. I use                                                                               authenticator: com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthenticator
authorizer: com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthorizer

Comment: authentication_options:
    enabled: true
    default_scheme: internal
    other_schemes:[]
    scheme_permissions: true
    allow_digest_with_kerberos: true
    plain_text_without_ssl: warn
    transitional_mode: disabled

Comment: Please paste the connection refused line from your log file.  DSE Graph does not require Kerberos.